# Dismiss searchBar programmatically in Swift 2.x and iOS9

Tags: ios, swift, tableview, uisearchbar, searchbar

I'm using a searchBar as a filter for a tableView.
I've read in several posts that including

```
self.definesPresentationContext = true
```

Dismisses the searchBar, but that's not my case.
What I want to achieve is that as soon as a user taps on the bar it dismisses the search closing it if some conditions are not satisfied.

I also tried

searchController.active = false

with no result. Anyone can help? Thanks

Comment: "What I want to achieve is that as soon as a user taps on the bar it dismisses the search" No, I'm not understanding what you want to do. If "some conditions are not satisfied", why is the search bar present and enabled? The way to handle this is to prevent the user from tapping on the search bar inappropriately in the first place, not to surprise the user by suddenly dismissing something.

Comment: If I don't show the searchBar how the user know that he can activate it? I was thinking that showing a message after the tap would be a good idea. Do you have a better solution?

Comment: "Do you have a better solution" I think I _gave_ you a better solution. Basic rules of software design: don't surprise the user, don't mislead the user, don't make a fool of the user. If the user can't do a thing, don't give him/her the means to do that thing. Conversely, don't give the user a piece of interface whose only effect is to put up an alert saying "You're an idiot".

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
[searchController.searchBar setHidden:YES];
```

You'll probably also want to dismiss the presentingViewController.

Although as matt points out, this is kind of an odd way of doing it. You're better off displaying an alertView if the conditions are not met and not even showing the searchBar.

Comment: actually in Swift 2.x is searchController.searchBar.enable = true, but it leave a blank space, otherwise it could be nice to disable it leaving it visible, such as having an alpha channel